# Can you use <c:otherwise> with <c:if> or only with <c:when>?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf, jstl, jsp-tags

I have searched StackOverflow for `<c:if>` and `<c:otherwise>` and have found some information but not exactly what I'm looking for. `<c:otherwise>` seems designed as follows:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${somecondition}">
        <%-- do stuff --%>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${someothercondition}">
        <%-- do other stuff --%>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <%-- do other other stuff --%>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

(so like a switch statement basically).

However, none of the other questions that I found were able to explicitly tell me whether this is the only way you can use `<c:otherwise>` (although they do seem to hint at it). Can you have

```
<c:if test="${somecondition}">
        <%-- do stuff --%>
</c:if>
<c:otherwise>
    <%-- do other stuff --%>
</c:otherwise>
```

(like an if/else) or is this wrong?

(Please do check my tags. I'm having to use/learn JSPs, Javascript and JQuery all at the same time and consequently sometimes get mixed up which new thing is which new language.)

Comment: @XtremeBiker That's one of the questions I looked at. The answers say to use choose/when/otherwise for if/else type statements but it's not clarified whether this is *a way of doing it* or *the only way to do it*. It doesn't answer the question I asked in the title.

Comment: Look at my answer, I think it fits it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use it without `<c:choose />`. JSTL differs simple conditional tags and conditional block executions:

> The **if** tag allows the conditional execution of its body according to the value of the test attribute.
>
> The **choose** tag performs conditional block execution by the embedded when subtags. It renders the body of the first when tag whose test condition evaluates to true. If none of the test conditions of nested when tags evaluates to true, then the body of an otherwise tag is evaluated, if present.

So you definitely need a conditional block (`<c:choose />`) in order to use `<c:otherwise />`.

**See also:**

- [JSTL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnakk/index.html)
- [Core Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL5.html)

Comment: The link you gave appears to indicate that conditional tags are a *subtype* of flow control tags. Am I reading it wrong? It also defines **both** `if` and `choose` as **both** flow tags and conditional tags. The key distinction it seems to be making is between conditional tags (if and choose) and iterator tags, so I'm not sure why you've linked it to show me the difference between if and choose. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I misread it, the `if` tag performs a unique test based in which it executes its body. Instead, `choose` performs a conditional block execution. The difference is that the first only allows a single condition, while the second is a whole conditional block. So `otherwise` goes in the block only ;-) Gonna update the answer